# Show a image user field on the Author page with ACF/advanced custom fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I want to show a custom Avatar image field on the author page. The following code is working for me, but shows as can be guesses the field of the current user. It should show the avatar field of the specific author.

````
the_field('avatar', 'user_'. $user_ID);
?>
    
<img src="<?php the_field('avatar', 'user_'. $user_ID); ?>" width="50" height="50"> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Need to grab the Author ID... You can use `get_queried_object_id()` for this on the `author.php` template like below:

```
<img src="<?php the_field('avatar', 'user_'. get_queried_object_id()); ?>" width="50" height="50" />
```

Comment: '$author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
$author_badge = get_field('avatar', 'user_'. $author_id );

?>
<img src="<?php echo $author_badge['url']; ?>" />'


I tried this, but sadly it didn't work. I use woody snippets to show in on the Author Archive page.

Answer (score 0):

simply use get_users()

```
$siteUsers = get_users( array( 'role__in' => array( 'administrator', 'subscriber' ) ) ); // u can change
    foreach ( $siteUsers as $user ) {
        echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</span><br />';
        echo '<img src="' . esc_attr( get_field('field_name', 'user_'.$user->ID) ) .'" alt="' . esc_attr( $user->display_name ) . '" /><br />';
    }
```